# Windows 8 random mouse bug

Tags: windows-8, mouse

I have been experiencing a quite annoying bug on all three of my windows 8 PCs. The bug is the following:

The mouse randomly gets positioned on the screen when I do not move it for 1-2 minutes. The problem appears regardless of the running applications, even with full screen applications like youtube or while gaming (spectator mode). I do not move the mouse. The proof for this is that when I watch a video on youtube, the mouse just appears out of nowhere, while the scrollbar does not appear on the bottom of the screen how it would had I moved the mouse.

Has anyone else experienced this same issue? Does anyone know a solution for this?